# How to disable Indicator Applet Application Menu for Eclipse

Tags: gnome-panel, eclipse, globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make indicator-appmenu ignore a specific application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6784/is-it-possible-to-make-indicator-appmenu-ignore-a-specific-application)

I recently installed the Indicator Applet Application Menu but unfortunately it does not work with Eclipse.
So I was wondering if it is possible to disable by using a command line parameter for example.