# How do I enable or disable the global application menu?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I'm fairly excited for Unity, as it looks like a promising new direction for Ubuntu.  However, I do have a concern - will it be possible to use Unity without the global menu?

I have my window manager set to focus-follows-mouse/sloppy focus, and find the productivity gains to be immense. Sloppy focus is incompatible, however, with global menus, as it is possible for the focus to change while you move from window to menu.

Will Unity support an option to use window menus while still using Unity?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

### 11.04 - 13.10

Yes, the Desktop version of Unity will use the global menu by default.

- To disable the global menu remove the [indicator-appmenu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu) [image: Install indicator-appmenu]
  package, then log out and back in.

Unity will continue to run without it and your menus will appear inside the application windows as normal. You can also tell the appmenu to [ignore specific applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6784/is-it-possible-to-make-indicator-appmenu-ignore-a-specific-application) if you're having a problematic app.

The command line way to remove the package is:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

**Removing the appmenu will break the HUD feature**

Comment: There is an utility that helps this: see http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/unsettings-tool-to-disable-global-menu.html

Comment: I hate the global menu and for that reason mac os too. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: @Rmano thx vm! good I read it.. your comment should actually be an answer as it works great and I can keep my indicator-appmenu!!! if you do it, point out so I come promptly vote up!

Comment: good option but I have a problem with QT applications (notepadqq for instance): the menu dissapear at all

Comment: In many cases it might be better to instead use the other answer to move the menu to the title bar. However removing the appmenu package will solve the problem of having no menu with x11 forwarding where as changing it in the settings wont do that.

Answer (score 30):

### 14.04

The Global Menu can be optionally switched in favour of Local Integrated Menus (LIM) - aka - more traditional window based menus.

The reason for this additional ability is ostensibly due to the increasing prevalence of high-resolution displays and as such the perceived mouse-travel from application to the global-menu would be relatively large.

To toggle the global menu off or on can be achieved via the appearance control-panel applet:

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

Once clicked, the application menus appear within the window decoration as shown here:

[image: pic]

---

Command line.

The above can be achieved using the terminal command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus true
```

Integrated menus can be disabled (i.e. switch global menu back on)

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus false
```

---

If you dont like Locally Integrated Menus then the old trick of removing `indicator-appmenu` still works although this will break the HUD

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

[image]

Comment: A bit more about how these menus work: [Better Late Than Never: Ubuntu Add Locally Integrated Menus to 14.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/locally-integrated-menus-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: "in window title bars" works perfectly, this global menu was utterly annoying when using Gimp.. thx!!

Comment: While the "locally integrated menus" option still hides them (irritatingly) `sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu` actually gets the menus permanently back below the title bars. I don't notice anything "broken" - care to explain that note?

Comment: This also works for 16.04, but the screenshots would be slightly different.

Answer (score 25):

For reference, here is how to disable the global menu on a per application basis: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu#Troubleshooting

> To disable appmenu support on a per application basis, set the
>   UBUNTU_MENUPROXY variable to null, with:
>
> ```
> env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
> ```
>
> the env keyword is useful if your trying to launch the application
>   with the ALT-F2 shortcut.

Answer (score 25):

### 11.04 - 13.10 - How to disable the global menu (appmenu / application menu)

#### For current user only, all applications

Add this to ~/.gnomerc and log out of the desktop and in again:

```
STARTUP="env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= $STARTUP"
```

#### For current user only, only applications launched from the shell

Add this to ~/.bashrc and restart the shell:

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
```

#### For current user only, only for specific applications launched from the shell

Add lines like this to ~/.bashrc and restart the shell:

```
alias gvim='UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= gvim'
```

Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/132581/32651.

#### For current user only, only for specific application launchers

See https://askubuntu.com/a/6802/32651.

#### For all users, all applications (fix it in /etc)

Create config file with fix (note that the parentheses are part of the command):

```
(umask 022; echo UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy)
```

After this, log out of the desktop and in again.

To remove the fix:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
```

Based on http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html.

#### For all users, all applications (uninstall packages)

Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-appmenu
```

Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu
```

After this, log out of the desktop and in again.

To undo, just install the packages again: `sudo apt-get install [...]`

From http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html.

#### Notes 1

Just doing

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

will still give problems with
[gvim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim)
and
[image viewers etc.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105889/can-i-completely-disable-the-menu-proxy)
since `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` will still be set to `'libappmenu.so'` by
the `appmenu-gtk` and `appmenu-gtk3` packages.

#### Notes 2

The default value is `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY='libappmenu.so'`.
The `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=` statement clears the variable.
Note that `export [...]` is not required when changing an already existing variable.

#### See also

- Gvim might spit out this warning 25 seconds after being started:
  `** (gvim:20320): WARNING **: Unable to create
  Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached`
  To fix this, either disable global menu, at least for gvim, or fix
  [gvim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim).
- Delayed in-window menu creation is a problem in
  [image viewers etc.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105889/can-i-completely-disable-the-menu-proxy),
  for example eog.
  To fix this, disable the global menu properly, at least for those applications.
- Get both global menu and in-window menu:
  APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1
  See https://askubuntu.com/a/6802/32651.

#### References

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu#Troubleshooting

Comment: Recent upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 broke my old settings and had the global menu bar enabled. Thanks for your detailed answer, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I have been successfully using unity with focus follows mouse and the global menu by only accessing the application menu via the f10 key shortcut. In many ways this is better than moving the mouse away from where ever you were focused on anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### 11.10

To disable the menu, instead of removing the indicator-appmenu you could hide its shared library file:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/indicators/5/libappmenu.so /usr/lib/indicators/5/libappmenu.so.old
```

and to reenable, undo it:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/indicators/5/libappmenu.so.old /usr/lib/indicators/5/libappmenu.so
```

[source](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1598-howto-disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal)

Answer (score 1):

### 18.04

Maybe there is an more-obvious way that i missed, but this somehow did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweaks
```

Go to "Top Bar"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### 11.10

I successfully disabled the global application menu by following the advice from http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-disable-global-menu-in-ubuntu-11-10-tip/.

I deinstalled the packages appmenu-gtk3, appmenu-gtk and appmenu-qt by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

Apparently, you can get the functionality back by reinstalling the packages.