# move main menu from top panel to top of the window?

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Unity support disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

Is there a way to move program's main menu (The one that says File, Settings, Help, ....) from the top panel Unity's panel to the top of the window, like it was before? I have 25" display and if small window open on the right side of the screen it is kind of annoying to move cursor to another corner of the screen to press go to the menu. Or if I need to go to the menu of not active window I must always click on and only then will be able to access menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to remove the package `indicator-appmenu`.

`sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu`

If you remove this package your menus will go back to normal.

Comment: Thanks    sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk   works perfectly!