# Is it possible to configure the menubars to stay on their associated window in Unity?

Tags: unity, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Unity support disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

The Unity interface displays the menubars of the applications on the top panel. This makes sense in a netbook or other limited gui contexts but it an unnecessary optimisation for large desktop displays, is it possible to change this behaviour?, if not, why not?, it seems to go against the culture of Linux to restrict the tweaking users can apply to their systems

Answer (score 0):

It works the way you want to me. When the application is maximized, the menu bar combines with the superior bar, but when you restore the window, it has its own bar, so it seems to be configurable since it works different to us. I was having troubles with unity so I did `unity --restart` and restarted the system. maybe that can help. Also, make sure that your graphics drivers are up to date.