# How can I keep menu bar on the applicaton on unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Unity support disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

I want to display the menu of the application in application top not in the unity bar. How to do this? It is possible?