# Can I remove the global menu and, instead, have it on each window?

Tags: globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Unity support disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

The title is the question. I need these characters to post.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?  I am not sure what you are asking.  Also, would you provide some details (e.g., Ubuntu 10.10)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the global menu and use the menus directly in the windows, like in previous Ubuntu versions, assuming you are using 11.04, you just need to remove the package indicator-appmenu by typing

> sudo apt-get remove  indicator-appmenu

into a console (and probably reentering your session).