# unity top menu at top of screen

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Unity support disabling the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

Is there an option with ubuntu unity to put the top menu bar back to the active window of the application ?
When you are using a desktop with 1920x1200 and a window at the bottom of the page, it's a long distance to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

You could remove it completely.

1. [Open a terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting%20a%20Terminal)
2. Type `sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-appmenu`
3. Logout or reboot

Comment: Thanks for this replay. After logout and login I got it right.

Comment: You are welcome and don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it solve my problem partially.. How can I make the windows chrome along with the max/min/close buttons to be visible when the windows is maximized?