# Application Menu for RubyMine

Tags: 11.04, appmenu

I noticed that there are some applications (e.g., RubyMine) that are not integrated with the Global Menu.

For LibreOffice I've seen that there already are fixes.

How do you make an app like RubyMine integrate well with the Global Menu?
If there is no current solution, what do you have to do to fix this (and give it back to the community)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Java Applications and Unity.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/768966

One option is to follow this:

[How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

Answer (score 0):

There is a java library that tries force global menu in Java Swing applications. It's called [jayatana](https://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana).

It creates Global Menu for Swing applications, like NetBeans IDE, Jetbrains IDEs (like PHPStorm, RubyMine, etc), IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio, etc.

**For 12.04**

See this tutorial and follow the OpenJDK or OracleJDK method: http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/

**For 13.10, 14.04 and 14.10**

On Trusty, Jayatana has it's own PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

Restart the IDE.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution, but it didn't work with 14.10, any ideas ?
(Note: i'm using Oracle's JDK)

Comment: @MhdSyrwan Probably authors just didn't update yet to support 14.10. I saw just now, and the package was published to 14.10. Can you try again?

Comment: I can find the package `jayatana`, but nothing happens after installing it and restarting `rubymine`