# How can I always show the close, minimise & maximise buttons into their own windows?

Tags: unity, 11.10, window-buttons

Ubuntu 11.10 hides the close, min and max buttons in the top panel. Is there a way to bring  all that back into the actual window and not in the panel?

Not just the buttons, but also the File, Edit menus back into their actual windows?

Answer (score 6):

This command brings menus and controls to their own windows:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

This moves the controls into the window, but only when the window is restored. When maximised, the controls go back at the top, but that's OK because it's maximised anyway.

Removing the menu entirely (same answer):

- [How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/does-unity-support-disabling-the-global-application-menu)

Comment: I've come across a slight issue with the above fix. If you have a window maximised in the background, and a restored window in the foreground, the restored window will show the close, min and max buttons in its own window just fine, but the maximised window in the backgound does not show it's buttons, so I can't close the maximised background window until I first click on that window to bring it to the foreground. Is there a way to 'fix' this?