# Always show close, minimize, maxmize buttons

Tags: unity, window-buttons

In Unity I have to mouse over the top-left to see the close, minimize, and maximize buttons.  For some reason, this is really annoying to me.  How can I make those buttons always visible?

[This doesn't do what I want (it just permanently shows File, Edit, ... menus).](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64831/how-can-i-always-show-the-close-minimise-maximise-buttons-into-their-own-wind)

[This is closely related, but not the same, and does not have a solution.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81175/how-can-i-always-show-the-close-minimise-and-maximise-buttons-on-their-windows)

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.3 LTS.

Comment: The second question you linked says it is a bug, unless fixed, I am afraid you will have to wait.

Comment: Why don't you use a more customizable distro instead of getting annoyed?

Comment: @vasa1 Chicken before the egg. Getting annoyed comes first, using a different distro comes second.

Comment: @Jobin You might be right, but that person was asking for something slightly different (separate buttons for each application). Also, that question is from 2011 and might not be accurate any more.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve this only because of lucky.

I was searching for the same answer. First I disabled the menus from the windows doing the commands:

sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt indicator-appmenu

Then I restarted the pc and then I went to Appearance Configuration > Behavior (I am using portuguese version so I dont know if this is the correct translation). And then there is a check box "Show menus" on "the title bar".

That solved the problem for me.