# Where are the Firefox close and minimise buttons when window is maximised?

Tags: unity, gnome, firefox

When I maximise a window in Ubuntu 14.0.4, I get the close and minimise buttons at the top left. Here's TeXStudio when it's maximised:

[image: TeXStudio is maximised]

So why does this not happen with Firefox (58.0.2)?

[image: Firefox is maximised]

I don't *think* this question is the same as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/64831/269136), but to be honest I don't understand what that other one is asking.

Comment: Look on the right side when FF is max.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There's nothing there!

Comment: You can always switch to traditional desktop environment as Xfce or MATE DE. All buttons are in place here.