# How do I disable the app menu at the user level?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I'm Trying to disable the App Menu feature (which drops all applications menu to the top panel) on Ubuntu 11.10.

Two solutions found up to now :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

or

```
echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
```

Both are system wide solutions. How could I set it in the user environment? I tried to set it in ~/.xprofile ... without success.

Thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Several options for current-user-only and system-wide global menu disabling can be found here:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/133005/32651

Comment: This is better as a comment.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Why? Should I have duplicated the information from the linked answer in order to make this a proper answer? Isn't that problematic in case of updates to the linked answer?

Comment: The general consensus agrees that only a link and intro text is better as a comment, while actual content exceeding a link is an answer.

Comment: OK. I don't quite understand why that would be better, at least in this case, but I will keep it in mind for next time. Thanks for the feedback.