# How to get the old menu in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: menu, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

I recently upgraded to 11.10 from 10.04. After the upgrade, the menu is shifted to the top column, which is pretty annoying.

I would prefer the old version where the menu is attached to the window itself.

Any idea how to get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove appmenu and appmenu indicator and related packages:

`sudo apt-get purge indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk`