# Can I remove the buttons (min, max, close) from the unity panel and put them back on the window?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, window-buttons

In unity 2d, the buttons on a maximized window are by default placed above the launcher on autohide. TBH I hate it when stuff autohides, and was wondering if they can be moved (on a maximized window, minimized no problems) to the right side, under the Me Menu.

Possible? I have the dash on always visible. The only program that doesn't give me this problem is Chrome, because when i deselect "Use System Title and Bars" it puts the buttons right there under the Me Menu. Can't this be done for all programs?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can remove the "indicator-appmenu", and it will become as it was in Lucid, and not sticking to the panel on maximize,

as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80160/how-to-get-the-old-menu-in-ubuntu-11-10) question.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I just tested this out, the max, min, close buttons are still stuck to the unity panel, although the menu is no longer stuck. I'm looking through gnome-tweak but there's nothing to configure it. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is impossible in current version of unity