# Menu application in terminal and Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, command-line, menu

I have a problem to display the menu commands in the window of the nautilus and the terminal (in simple words can not display the file .. help etc..) I see the bar but no writing .. Can you help me see the other windows in the browser type, etc. .. LibreOffice

Image of objective -->

[image]

I Use ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell

thks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable the global application menu? ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

Comment: Following the link given to you I have not solved the problem, nothing has changed .. how can I reset the settings?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/problemamenu.png/

Comment: I solved the problem completely uninstalling gnome-shell

login to Unity and with terminal launch 

sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell

after this step, proceed with sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Answer (score 1):

OP posted the answer as a comment

> I solved the problem completely uninstalling `gnome-shell` login to Unity and with terminal launch
>
> `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell` after this step, proceed with `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Or find gnome-shell in the Software Centre:

[image: Install via the software center]