# video gets corrupt after converting ogv to any format using ffmpeg

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg

I was trying to convert ogv video to avi using ffmpeg. It does convert without any error but the output video seems to be corrupt. Does not matter which format I convert it to, out put is same as shown in screenshot.

> ffmpeg command : `ffmpeg -i original.ogv -sameq converted.avi`
>
> ffmpeg version : 0.7
>
> ubuntu : 11.10 - 64 bit

**Original video screenshot**

[image: Original video screenshot]

**Converted video screenshot**

[image: Converted video screenshot]

Comment: You cant expect same quality after video conversion 
i got the similar output after converting ogv file to mp4 file 
but file size doubled
i tried winff(gui of ffmpeg)

Comment: @AboobackerMk Its not about quality. Quality can be changed with appropriate parameters. Problem is, output video has distorted text and images as you can see in second screenshot.

Comment: you would have better results with ffmpeg -i original.ogv -sameq -f mp4 converted.mp4

Comment: @duffydack No luck, output is same. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11067845/converted_mp4.png

Comment: 2 things to try then.  1: compile a newer ffmpeg/x264 from source http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095 - it's simple. or 2:  use kazam for screencasting, it uses webm as output

Comment: @duffydack I will try kazam but are you sure its version issue in ffmpeg ? I tried to compile latest version of ffmpeg but got all messed up. Will try it again.

Comment: I have converted ogv to mp4/avi with ffmpeg a few times without issues.  I've always used the compiled version.  I made it into a script to automate it getting newer version :)

Comment: @duffydack why don't you copy and paste your second comment as answer so that i can mark it as accepted answer and also thanks for pointing out Kazam screencaster. It was awesome.

Comment: @Rojan, ok, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options at least for you.

1. Install Kazam screencaster which supports outputting of webm format and compatible with uploading to Youtube where .OGV is not without conversion.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install kazam
   ```
2. Compile a newer ffmpeg from source to convert OGV.  A very easy to follow guide is [Compile latest FFMPEG and X264](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095).

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: use Handbrake.

---

Ha. I had this exact issue with `ffmpeg` yesterday when making an animated gif for this question:

- [Can I completely disable the menu proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105889/can-i-completely-disable-the-menu-proxy)

I used gtk-recordMyDesktop to record the screen but when I tried to do anything with `ffmpeg`, it just filled up with artefacts. To compound issues, I tried converting with desktop video editing software (I wanted to crop too) and they all just blew up. Probably something to do with the 3840x1200 frame size.

I'm sure there's a pure-`ffmpeg` for removing these artefacts but I just installed Handbrake and converted the ogv to a high-quality mp4 file, which I then used in `ffmpeg` to convert out to my animated gif.

Pain in the bum, but it doesn't take long for short clips, and in your case, it might even simplify things.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. Its certainly is pain in the bum :)

Comment: Thanks!  Handbrake worked.  ffmpeg and mencoder have the same bug, but Handbrake does not.  Instructions on installing Handbrake for ubuntu can be found at http://askubuntu.com/questions/107915/installing-and-downloading-handbrake-in-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Little squares everywhere in converted output from ogv. I tried mencoder and obtained the same result:

```
  mencoder original.ogv -vc theora -ovc x264 -o converted.avi
```

until I explicitly gave the -vc theora option:

```
  mencoder original.ogv -vc theora -ovc x264 -o converted.avi
```

This time the output was fine.

I also uninstalled ffmpeg 0.7.3, downloaded the latest source from the git repository, compiled and installed it. Now the same ffmpeg command converts ogv videos nicely.

HTH