# Can I get gnome-shell's drop-down menus in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

Just a quick question, in gnome-shell you get those little white menus that drop down from the title of the application but in Unity you have it as a separate window. Is there any way to get those drop down menus in Unity? I much prefer the look of them over the separate windows.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to having menus in the application window of itself?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/unsettings-tool-to-disable-global-menu.html ?

Install unsettings (see howto in the Webupd8 site) and disable the global menu.