# How do I disable app menu in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

How to disable the app menu functionality ("global menu") in LibreOffice, Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 4):

The gtk-desktop integration activates the unitymenu if unity is available. This can be prevented by uninstalling libreoffice-gtk, which also removes all themeing and results in a very ugly LibreOffice without unity integration.

Comment: Bjoern Michaelsen -- That worked. As you indicated it is ugly but at least I can use LibreOffice now. This upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 has some terribly nasty side effects even beyond this one. For instance alt-Tab not identifying some applications which were minimized and therefore unrecoverable. Bad show, ubuntu, very bad show.

Comment: upgrading/updating often scares me, the global menu is so annoying and troublesome..; this answer fix for me on 12.10, it also enforces removal of libreoffice-gnome, but til now I see no problems on that, and the "ugly interface" is not that ugly... and most importantly it works fine now what is MUCH better than looking pretty :)

Comment: This fix also works in Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 3):

Let me quote an answer from [How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu). This is how you disable the app menu on a per application basis :

> To disable appmenu support on a per application basis, set the
>   UBUNTU_MENUPROXY variable to null, with:
>
> ```
> env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
> ```
>
> the env keyword is useful if your trying to launch the application
>   with the ALT-F2 shortcut.

You'll find more details on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu#Troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't believe this works for Libreoffice, because if I'm not wrong, global menus for certain applications (like Libreoffice and Firefox) are implemented in an application-specific manner.

Answer (score 3):

As Flimm already stated, removing `lo-menubar` won't remove LibreOffice's Global Menu.

To remove LibreOffice's Global Menu, you need to remove this package:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

Comment: This did not work in 13.04... The menu is still in the top bar...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "global menu" just for libre office this could work:

```
sudo apt-get remove lo-menubar
```

If you want to remove the "global menu" from ALL applications you should do the following on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

If you want to put it back then use this on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

I hope this could help you. Good luck!

Comment: `lo-menubar` in Ubuntu 12.10 is just a dummy package, so removing it won't have any effect.

Comment: These worked in 12.04, but with 12.10 and 13.04, the LibreOffice menu is integrated in libreoffice-gtk so removing those things does not help with LibreOffice.