# How do I remove window buttons and file menus from panel in 12.10?

Tags: unity, 12.10, appmenu, metacity

I am a Gnome 3 fan, but after upgrading to 12.10 I feel like I want to give Unity another try. One problem that I have with Unity though is the menu bars in programs and window buttons displaying in the panel. I HATE this, can someone please tell me how to stop Unity from doing this?

Note: I found a site that explains how to stop a majority of windows from displaying the menus in the panel, but most of them still have the window buttons in the panel. I like to have my buttons on the right, but when a window is maximized, Unity displays the window buttons on the left of the panel. I want to stop Unity from taking control of my maximized windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu

Comment: Thank you for your input fossfreedom, however not relevant. Please read the entire question before posting. More specifically the part beginning after "NOTE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I think it's the tool that would get you the furthest:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/unsettings-a-comprehensive-tweaking-tool-for-unity

Maybe it's worth a spin, however I use gnome shell, so I don't know.