# Eclipse fails to run

Tags: eclipse

I've installed Scala IDE plugin and tweaked eclipse.ini file according to their suggestions [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/advancedsetup/index.html). For some reason eclipse gets upset about that and errors on launch.

It seems to work if I comment out single line:

```
-vmargs
```

I don't understand, what's the problem here?

This is my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-Xss1M
-server
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

This is the message I get when eclipse fails to launch:

[image: error message]

**UPDATE:** Eclipse version: 4.3 (Kepler) 64bit, Ubuntu version: 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) 64bit, Java version: Oracle 1.7_40 64bit

**UPDATE2:** Including my `configuration/config.ini`:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Mon Oct 14 19:30:48 BST 2013
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20130327-2119.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=true
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.v20120524-1707.jar
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
```

**UPDATE3:** I run eclipse from it's folder in command line like this: `gksudo ./eclipse &`. I have to run it as a root because otherwise there is a bug that disables main menu dropdowns. `which eclipse` gives me nothing, probably because I just downloaded/unpacked it directly from eclipse.org and there is no command associated with it.

Comment: Run correct 32-bit or 64-bit version ?

Comment: @crafter Included all versions in update.

Comment: How did you install Eclipse exactly? And I see you're using Ubuntu 13.10 - this hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I see two problems: You have duplicate entries namely '-vmargs', '-Xms...' and '-Xmx...' but eclipse should still run with those (fix it anyway). The real kicker is the last entry in the dialog "-jar /home/..." This shouldn't be there. I bet this comes from the starter script which calls eclipse. Please post it in your question.

Comment: @MadMike I've included `configuration/config.ini` - is that what you meant? The starter file is binary, it's just called `eclipse`

Comment: do you get the same error when you open a terminal a start it with the command `eclipse`? What is the output of `which eclipse`?

Comment: @MadMike Included the answers in the latest update.

Comment: [Disabling your global menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu) for eclipse might give you your main menu back without resorting to `gksudo`.

Comment: @MadMike Thanks, although the menu is not my main concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned up your eclipse.ini. It is tested it with Eclipse 4.2 Juno. Please report if it works with your scala plugin:

```
--startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xss1M
-server
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

For future reference: Be careful adding options to you eclipse.ini. Take special care about what goes before `-vmargs` and what after it.

Also, no option should be set twice.