# Menu bars for Gnome apps not being replaced by global menu

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10, menu

I have recently had some issues in fixing my nvidia graphics card issues after a new Ubuntu 13.10 install - so I may have accidentally screwed up some settings.

My problem is that some apps keep their own menu when it should only be shown in the global menu. What I mean is that if I open *some* applications (e.g. gnome-terminal, disk usage analyzer, system monitor, totem and others) I see both the application menu on the app itself as well as the global menu. It doesn't matter if I maximise the window or not.

After my initial install it all worked ok, i.e. all menus where only shown in the global menu, until my recent issue with my nvidia drivers.

How can I get application menus to *only* be shown in the global menu (as per the default Ubuntu behavior)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to install [indicator-appmenu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu) will solve the problem.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

Take a look at [How do I disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)