# Texmaker not displaying the menu bar with Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 14.04

I installed Texmaker 4.2 (Qt5) on my Ubuntu 14.04 (Gnome 3). The installation went smooth but I don't have a menu bar and therefore I can not configure the Texmaker. My program looks like this screenshot
[image]
<sub>(source: [xm1math.net](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmakerQT5_ubuntu.png))</sub>

Since my program looks like this:
[image]

the screenshot from the developer I assume there is no bug. Can someone please tell me how I am able to access the menu bar and configure the program. Is this a Gnome shell issue?

Comment: Have you tried to hover your mouse on "Texmaker" in the panel? In the bright new world of global menus, it should be appear just over there. I do have a menu in my intallation.

Comment: I did and the result can be seen in the second screenshot in my post. I do only have the option to quit the program. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The menu in the panel should be there in Unity. In Gnome Shell the menu should be in the window; but sometime the installations with both gnome shell and unity can become highly confused. You can try http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-global-application-menu   Here is how to look in my Ubuntu Gnome: http://imgur.com/oglEwYe

Comment: I see. I tried to blacklist texmaker from using the global menu following this manual (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/unity-global-menu-can-now-be-disabled.html) but it does not work. I don't want to disable the global menu for all applications. I might need to create a post about the blacklisting not working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have both Unity and Gnome shell installed and use gnome shell. I did not have this issue with Texmaker 4.3 (QT5): http://imgur.com/X3o9LNf

Comment: Using the 4.4.1 version of Texmaker build with QT4 does fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and solved it by **maximizing the Texmaker window before rolling mouse on the program header**. Also it works if you place mouse over the panel on the very top of the screen even without maximizing (not the panel with the close-minimize-maximize buttons). Hope it could also help you!

**[Update]**: screenshot can be found here:
[image]

Red arrow shows where you likely tried to put cursor on, and green arrow shows position where it should be put - at least how it worked for me.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. Could you please add a screen shot.

Comment: I have added a link to the screenshot to my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for posting your screen shot. You seem to use Unity and I am using the gnome shell. Since I think my problem is related to not using Unity I don't think that the behaviour you are experiencing with Texmaker is not replicable on my system.