# Locally integrated menus (menus in title bars) only working selectively

Tags: 14.04, menu, menu-bar, locally-integrated-menus

I upgraded to 14.04 and enabled locally integrated menus. However, they seem to work on a randomly selective basis. I've tried a few applications out - Firefox and LibreOffice work, but Terminal and Nemo do not:

[image]

What's going on? How can I get the latter to integrate as per the former?

Comment: No, it's not. Like I said, it works, _selectively_. I want it to work for every application, the mismatch is the annoying part.

Comment: Aaah, I see. So I guess you did try enabling the menu's globally as described in the post. Please include any methods you have tried that have failed to fix the problem so we don't continue to provide solutions that don't work. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Nothing I've found even mentions this issue, so I can't troubleshoot it on my own.

Comment: check out the solutions on this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-global-application-menu. Although it doesn't **specifically** mention your issue, I believe the solution may be one in the same. The only way to find out is to give it a try. If it doesn't work, we know we have a bigger issue on our hands that we can better pinpoint by knowing what does and does not influence this behavior. Make sure you have indicator-appmenu installed. Then go to settings and make sure the option for global menus selected. There's even pictures posted step by step.

Comment: Only one post is relevant to my distribution version, and I've tried everything there to no avail. I do notice even fossfreedom's screenshot seems to have the same problem I do: Libreoffice's menu is in the title bar, whereas Terminal's is below.

Comment: ok so did you check to see if indicator-appmenu is installed? and have you checked your settings to see what they are as described anyway?

Comment: Like I said, I _**have**_ tried everything in that post.

Comment: If you tried the "solutions" and it did not help, I suggest you file a bug report. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

First, open gnome-terminal (terminal) and then click edit, select prefrences and then disable the option "show menubar by default in new terminals". Close the prefrences menu, right-click anywhere on the output area and de-select the option "show menubar" before closing the terminal.

Now, open a new terminal, right-click anywhere on the output area and select "show menubar". The menu should now display properly in the top panel instead of the window like it did before.

Next, click "terminal" in the top menu, select "prefrences" and this time **enable the option** "show menubar by default in new terminals".

The menu should now display in the top menu instead of in the window from now on and the problem should be fixed.

(tested on a newly installed ubuntu-desktop 14.04)

---

If you didn't already give this a try, you may want to see if this command-line option  works for those apps by disabling the integrated window menus for your user-profile using gsettings.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity integrated-menus false
```

---

As far as indicator-appmenu is concerned, you can check to see if it's installed by typing the following command in an open terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep indicator-appmenu
```

The output should list indicator-appmenu if it's installed which I'm sure it probably is but you never know, if not, you can install it or even **reinstall** it just for good measure like this.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-appmenu
```

Comment: All the gsettings option did was move the menu bar to the top of the screen (as before) for Firefox et al. Terminal's menu remained under the title bar of the window itself, even when fullscreen. Reinstalling appindicator did nothing.

Comment: @heidi Yeah, I think the Terminal's menu has to be disabled from the output interface manually. Did you try that yet?

Comment: I don't want to disable the menu! I just want it to be in the title bar like Firefox's!

Comment: @heidi Okay, here you go. I found a workaround and posted it to the answer above.

Comment: After opening the new terminal and selecting 'show menubar' it still shows below the title bar.

Comment: @heidi Also, I have `unity-tweak-tool`, `gnome-tweak-tool`, and `ccsm` installed.