# Corrupted program menu - repeated items

Tags: 14.04, unity, mysql-workbench

I've made a simple change in one of the saved connections in MySQL Workbench and suddenly the program menu got corrupted. It's showing one set of menu items for the program and then one set for every opened tab instead of switching the set of items based on which tab is opened.

[image: MySQL Workbench corrupted menu]

What I tried:

1. Restart program - I thought that that's what it would take.
2. Delete the whole profile (~/.mysql/workbench).
3. Restart Unity.
4. Restart the computer.
5. Completely remove MySQL Workbench and install the latest version (6.2.4-1ubu1404-amd64).

Neither of this helped so I'm quite puzzled. It looks like the problem is not just on the MySQL Workbench part but possibly it has something to do with... the window manager?

**Q1: Can the problem be related to the window manager or OS?**

**Q2: Is there anything that can be cleared/checked/updated/whatever regarding the program menus?**

Comment: What is the exact command you used in your item 5?

Comment: I used Synaptic to remove it and then installed a downloaded .deb file. However, none of it probably matters. I think there is a bug in MySQL Workbench because there are at least 2 other people who reported it in the past few days on a freshly created bug report mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been confirmed that this is a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75442) in the current (as of January 2015) version of MySQL Workbench so there is nothing to do but to wait for a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in the meanwhile is to disable the global menu system as described here:
[How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-global-application-menu)

You basically remove the package indicator-appmenu with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

This will make the menus appear in their own traditional menu bar for **all** applications. Some Ubuntu applications do not work well with this configuration though so it is not bullet proof solution.