# How can I make my Unity desktop look like this?

Tags: unity

How can I make my Unity desktop like this picture?

I want the position of close/minimize buttons to be on the toolbar beside the address bar like this:

[image]

This image looks like Gnome desktop but Ubuntu's menu is like this:

[image]

I mean, the close button in Ubuntu is on the top of the address bar but in first image the buttons are integrated in the address bar.

Comment: Do you want to [disable the global menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-global-application-menu)?

Comment: Or to autohide the launcher? (Hint: System Settings / Apperance / Behavior.)

Comment: i edited my question to better understand

Comment: You first screenshot is from Ubuntu 16.10 and the second is what it used to be up to 16.04. If you want the former but have the latter, just upgrade to 16.10 (be aware 16.10 is **not** LTS). The other way around isn't possible without some serious changes that will most likely break a lot of other things.