# Anydesk crashes after another user accepts remote connection

Tags: remote

I have installed anydesk application from this [url](https://tecadmin.net/install-anydesk-ubuntu/). However, when I tried to remote to my friend computer, my anydesk was closed immediately.

So to track this issue, I tried to start it with `sudo anydesk`, in terminal it show message:

```
(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.099: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.102: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.106: IA__gtk_signal_connect_full: assertion 'GTK_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

When I remote to my friend computer, and he accepted connection, in terminal show this message:

```
(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.099: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.102: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:21940): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:06:01.106: IA__gtk_signal_connect_full: assertion 'GTK_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'base::invalid_argument_exception_t'
```

And my anydesk was closed. I have no clue what cause this error, I tried to re-install it several times already, but still the same.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @lostlostlostlostlost, not yet

Comment: I had this problem a while back, and fixed it by installing gtk2.0 and gtk3.0. Worked fine until recently. Same problem with the program crashing on a successful connect.

Comment: @lostlostlostlostlost yeah I tried to install gtk2.0 and gtk3.0 already but it did not help solve the problem.

Comment: @houy-narun I believe this is bug within application itself and you should report to Anydesk.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue with the same error as you while restarting Anydesk.

The fix is very simple. Just follow the below steps:

1. Go to your home directory `~`.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show all hidden files.
3. You will find a `.anydesk` folder. Just delete that folder, remove your Anydesk and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965;anydesk
```

Comment: sorry i know it is long ago; I have tried but it does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue, didn't solve by removing .anydesk folder, solved by disabling the global menu (the thing that moves window menu into a panel)

Comment: I am encountering the same issue right now, and removing .anydesk followed by a reinstall doesn't work. Where can I find this option?

Comment: @MaximeBeau this isn't an Anydesk option but a desktop manager feature, try looking here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-global-application-menu