# Menu missing in Lotus notes 8 and Eclipse in Unity

Tags: unity, menu, appmenu

I installed lotus notes 8.5.2 on 10.10 netbook using unity desktop. At first lotus notes showed its menu. Suddenly (not sure if I did something) the menu disappeared. When I start up using gnome desktop, the menu still is there. Unity shows only the file menu for notes with the only entry for closing notes.

Comment: Hi. I don't think is related with the reported issue.
Eclipse works fine with the AppMenu in ubuntu >= 11.10.
Simply follow this instructions: https://bugs.launchpad.net/eclipse/+bug/618587/comments/46

Answer (score 11):

Actually there is a way to support global menus for Eclipse:
Use VI to edit the following file: `sudo vi /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so`.
Search for *Eclipse* (type `/Eclipse`) and replace the E character with an X (type `rX`).
Save it (type `:wq`) and run `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: When I tried to open that file with gedit or vi it opens up like if you tried to open a binary. Lots of \00,I did search for Eclipse but there isn't any E's around it. Unless you mean the name Eclipse so it says Xclipse? Gedit also warns that I could corrupt the file if I edit it.

Comment: @russjr08 See my updates about how to do it

Comment: Wow that worked!! Thank you soo much! Marking as answer :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Netbeans too?

Comment: Need to use bvi, vi will corrupt the file.

Comment: If you spoiled your libappmenu-library zu can refresh it with
sudo apt-get install --reinstall appmenu-gtk

Answer (score 3):

This is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/618587) in how SWT applications (like Eclipse and Lotus Notes) handle the appmenu.

As a workaround, create this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
_path_to_downloaded_eclipse_/eclipse
```

If you installed eclipse with Software Centre, then use `which eclipse` to determine the path.

Make that file [executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35478/how-do-i-mark-a-file-as-executable-via-a-gui) and try running it. You can use "Main Menu" (search in the Dash) to create a launcher for it so it shows up in the Dash.

That should move the menus from the Unity top bar to the eclipse window. Once the bug is fixed, you will be able to run eclipse normally.

Another question has a much more thorough description of [disabling appmenu for any application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6784/is-it-possible-to-make-indicator-appmenu-ignore-a-specific-application/6802#6802).

Comment: @Jorge: I'm a bit confused. I think I answered this on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40775/ubuntu-unity-not-showing-all-eclipse-menus), so I guess Marco moved my answer for me?

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 with the Scala IDE version of Eclipse from Typesafe.  I have no /usr/lib/gtk... folder.  Installing gnome-shell didn't help.  This was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and has been reported. You may follow it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/eclipse/+bug/618587/comments/46). Could you try it, and tell us? (Write the commands exactly like this, because you can search and replace on **vim** by writing commands)

```
sudo apt-get install vim
sudo vim /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

The vim will appear. Write this: `/Eclipse`

Then, replace the E of *Eclipse* with an *X* by writing this: `rX`

Finally, just save by writing this: `ZZ`. **In caps, so you should do SHIFT+Z SHIFT+Z!**

The next step is maybe optional, I don't know:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same workaround: 
If you have a launcher on the desktop, you can insert this into the "Ccommand" line of the Launcher's properties page:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/eclipse/eclipse43jee/eclipse
```

Like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For Googlers, if you're getting this in Saucy Salamander, try this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221848