# Ubuntu Unity not showing all eclipse menus

Tags: unity, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu missing in Lotus notes 8 and Eclipse in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity)

Hi

I just upgraded to Natty and I was giving a sporting chance to Unity. There a lot of things I liked about it (ease of search, zooming, ...) but the issue that made me switch to "classic" is that eclipse was just showing 1 of the 10 menus (Windows) Any way I can coax Unity to show all ten of them?

Ciao
Stefano