# Emacs Unity global app menu integration stopped working in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, appmenu, emacs

Emacs' Unity global app menu integration stopped working when I upgraded to 11.10.  Anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: (One post per issue please! I'll edit out the eclipse bit, which you can find info for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/888697).

Answer (score 1):

It probably looks strange that I reply to such an old posting, but I also stumbled across this one when I looked for a solution how to integrate emacs into the Unity appmenu (global and locally integrated into window bar). So I dare to reply. Here are my two cents:

emacs 24 potentially integrates well with Unity, but it seems it is blacklisted by in a hardcoded way. There is a very simply way around this: to simple include it into the whitelist:

- open dconf editor (search "dconf" in the Unity dash)
- go to "com | canonical | unity-gtk-module"
- add emacs24 to whitelist, e.g. ['emacs24']

This is it, at least for me it works perfectly (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the MacBuntu theme and locally integrated menus).

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04, the following command does the job,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-gtk-module whitelist "['emacs24']"
```

Comment: This seem to do the trick even on modern Ubuntus. But I wonder why it is still not the default after all these years.