# Can I make Eclipse use the Ubuntu global menu?

Tags: 11.10, appmenu, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu missing in Lotus notes 8 and Eclipse in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity)

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and I'd like for it to use the global menu, like all the other applications on my system.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: This should not be closed as it is not a duplicate!