# Put Eclipse Menubar in Globalmenu?

Tags: eclipse, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu missing in Lotus notes 8 and Eclipse in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity)

I noticed that when I installed Eclipse (From the Repo) that the File, Edit, etc Menus are not in the global/appmenu bar. Is there a way to fix this?