# How to enable Global Menu for Eclipse in 12.10?

Tags: eclipse, 12.10, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Menu missing in Lotus notes 8 and Eclipse in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16736/menu-missing-in-lotus-notes-8-and-eclipse-in-unity)

I would like to know is there a way to enable global menu for Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.10?