# Disabling global menu for specific application in Saucy

Tags: 13.10, globalmenu

There used to be a way to start an application with global menu disabled: [Is it possible to make indicator-appmenu ignore a specific application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6784/is-it-possible-to-make-indicator-appmenu-ignore-a-specific-application)

One needed to set the variable UBUNTU_MENUPROXY.

This method no longer works. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it always worked, but it is important to run the application like this, for example: `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= leafpad` - the space between "=" and "l" is important. That is why it did not work for me.